# Integrate Groovy in an existent Web app

Tags: java, grails, groovy, groovyws

I have an existent web application, I'd like to add Groovy to this web app so that I can develop web service providers easily if possible. 
Is there a way to write a service class (like Grails service classes) and expose this class as ws without much pain ?

Grails uses the same thing : after adding one line to the service class, that class will be exposed automatically as a web service.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GroovyWS is a SOAP based implementation of Apache CXF.

After some quick searching I found two tutorials that may be of help.

One using Jersey and the other using Restlet. The Jersey one seems simpler.

[Creating RESTful services with Jersey and Groovy](http://gallemore.blogspot.com/2008/10/creating-restful-services-with-jersey.html)

[Building RESTful Web Apps with Groovy and Restlet, Part 1: Up and Running](http://blog.arc90.com/2008/06/04/building-restful-web-apps-with-groovy-and-restlet-part-1-up-and-running/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply,
Actually I'd like to bind my restful web service in a servlet that will dispatch the request to the appropriate node. the problem with the both examples that it declares a server on a different port.
The other constraint is that I'd like to run the WS inside the web application context .. so that I'll have access to the web app objects.

Comment: I think you would need Spring for that then to do the dependency injection. There's a book coming out soon [Making Java Groovy](http://www.manning.com/kousen/) that seems to cover what you may need. It's currently a MEAP.

Comment: Cool !
Thank you for your response.